# What is principal value in delta function integral?

Tags: fourier-transform, dirac-delta-distributions

The delta function may have different forms of definition. One related to Fourier transform is shown below,

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\!dt ~e^{i\omega t}~=~2\pi\delta(\omega).$$

then I wonder what if only the positive (or negative) frequency part be considered. We may run into singularity for the integral below,

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\!dt ~e^{i\omega t}~=~?$$

I find it's related to principal value. Can anyone give a solid explanation and derivation for this integral?

Comment: Why should the integral on half-domain be the half of the first result? $e^{iwt}$ is not even on the domain. Why do you expect the second result?

Comment: [The delta function is even](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function)

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: Your second integral is (by definition) the positive-frequency delta function $2\pi\delta_+(w)$. It has a well-known representation in terms of the distribution $\frac{1}{w+i0^+}$. In any case, I voted to migrate to math.SE.

Comment: The function under the integral oscillates with any $\omega \ne 0$, but does not oscillate for $\omega=0$. The oscillations cancel themselves from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$, but not form $0$ to $+\infty$. BTW this is not a definition of the Delta Function (or not a good one at least), but just a Fourier transform of it. You could say though that, if $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)\delta(0)dx=f(0)$, then $\int_0^{+\infty}f(x)\delta(0)dx=\dfrac{1}{2}f(0)$

Answer (score 5):

> my question is how to derive the second integral in the original
>   question.

Try using the [unit step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function) $u(t)$ to rewrite the integral as a Fourier transform:

$$\int_{0}^\infty\mathrm{d}t\,e^{i\omega t} = \int_{-\infty}^\infty\mathrm{d}t\,e^{i\omega t}\,u(t) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty\mathrm{d}\tau\,e^{-i\omega \tau}\,u(-\tau),\quad \tau = -t$$

So, the second integral is *Fourier transform of the time reversed unit step function*.  The Fourier transform of the unit step function can be looked up in a table of [Fourier transform pairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Tables_of_important_Fourier_transforms):

$$u(t) \leftrightarrow \left(\frac{1}{i\omega} + \pi\delta(\omega) \right) $$

Using the time reversal property, $\mathcal{F}\{x(-t)\} = X(-\omega)$, we have

$$\int_{0}^\infty\mathrm{d}t\,e^{i\omega t} = \frac{i}{\omega} + \pi\delta(\omega)$$

Answer (score 3):

So what does it mean to be a delta function? It means that something is a mathematical object which satisfies for all other nice $f$,
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} d\omega~f(\omega)~\delta(\omega) = f(0).$$
More formally, it turns out that the $\delta(\omega)$ can never truly be separated from the $\int_{-\infty}^\infty d\omega$ sign: our writing of $\delta(\omega)$ is really a failure of notation where we would want to actually describe something more like, $$\int_{\mathbb R} dt~\left[f \mapsto \int_{\mathbb R} d\omega ~e^{i\omega t} f(\omega)\right] = f\mapsto 2\pi~f(0),$$ where $\mapsto$ denotes a function which accepts a smooth function as input and integration (really, addition and multiplication) of such functions is done "pointwise" (so that $f + g = x\mapsto f(x) + g(x)$ for example).

## Setting up the integral

Anyway the general approach to this problem is to shift the subproblems off the real axis by an infinitesimal amount, so that $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty dt~e^{i\omega t} = 
\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\left(\int_{-\infty}^0 dt~e^{i(\omega - i \epsilon) t} + \int_0^{\infty} dt~e^{i(\omega + i\epsilon)t }\right),$$hence your question is actually one of the "stepping stones" we need to address in order to handle the above integrals. One finds of course,$$\int_0^\infty dt~ e^{(i\omega - \epsilon) t} = -\frac 1{i\omega - \epsilon} = \frac{i}{\omega + i \epsilon}, ~~\epsilon > 0,$$ or substituting in the fuller expression using $\mapsto$ we would find that this half-integral is, $$\int_0^\infty dt~\left[f \mapsto \int_{\mathbb R} d\omega~e^{i\omega t} f(\omega)\right] = f\mapsto \lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\int_{\mathbb R} d\omega~\frac{i}{\omega + i \epsilon}~f(\omega). $$ It is when we try to evaluate this with complex analysis that we need the Cauchy principal value.

### Contour deformation

Cauchy's integral theorem allows us to deform contours off the real line into the complex plane without changing the value. If we do this before we take the limit of $\epsilon \to 0$ we can make taking that limit very easy. So we deform the contour a little into the positive imaginary half of the plane around $\omega = 0$, a half-circle with radius $r$, which we will later shrink to zero size. So on this circle $\omega = r~e^{i\theta}$ with $\theta: \pi \to 0$ and thus $d\omega = i~r~e^{i\theta}~d\theta.$ To save some space let $k_\epsilon(\omega) = \frac i{\omega + i\epsilon},$ the resulting expression for the right-hand-side is,
$$f \mapsto \lim_{r\to 0^+}\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+} \left(\int_{-\infty}^{-r}d\omega ~k_\epsilon(\omega)~f(\omega) + \int_{r}^{\infty}d\omega ~k_\epsilon(\omega)~f(\omega) + \int_{\pi}^{0} i~r~e^{i\theta} d\theta~k_\epsilon(re^{i\theta})~f(r~e^{i\theta}) \right).$$
We can now take the limit $\epsilon \to 0^+$ by simply substituting $\epsilon = 0$ in here; this contour does not hit any singularities when we do so. We find that $k_0 = i/\omega$ and the first term in the limit as $r\to 0^+$ is just the Cauchy principal value of an integrand, while the rightmost term is also interesting due to cancellation of the a term $r e^{i\theta}$ from $d\omega$ with the term $1/(r e^{i\theta})$ from $k_0$: 
$$
f \mapsto \operatorname{PV}\int_{-\infty}^\infty d\omega ~\frac i\omega ~f(\omega) - \lim_{r\to 0^+} \int_{\pi}^{0} d\theta~f(r~e^{i\theta}).$$

So we can also take this limit as $r\to 0^+$ by direct substitution and we find,

$$\int_0^\infty dt~\left[f \mapsto \int_{\mathbb R} d\omega~e^{i\omega t} f(\omega)\right] = 
f \mapsto \operatorname{PV}\int_{-\infty}^\infty d\omega ~\frac i\omega ~f(\omega) + \pi~f(0).$$
If the principal value is understood as implied, one might instead write, $$ \int_0^\infty d\omega~ e^{i\omega t} = \frac{i}{\omega} + \pi~\delta(\omega).$$

## What about the other side of the original integral?

As one might imagine, the integral for negative $t$ is largely the reverse of this. Indeed one has $$\int_{-\infty}^0 dt~e^{(i\omega + \epsilon)t} = \frac{1}{i\omega + \epsilon} = \frac {-i}{\omega - i \epsilon}.$$ The principal value analysis is absolutely identical except that the numerator contains $-i$ rather than $+i$, but the semicircle must dip into the negative half-plane rather than the positive half plane, yielding:
$$f \mapsto \operatorname{PV}\int_{-\infty}^\infty d\omega ~\frac {-i}\omega ~f(\omega) + 
\lim_{r\to 0^+} \int_{-\pi}^{0} i~r~e^{i\theta} d\theta~\frac{-i}{r e^{i\theta}} ~f(r~e^{i\theta}).$$
Thus we have, perhaps surprisingly,
$$\int_{-\infty}^0 dt~e^{i\omega t} = - \frac{i}{\omega} + \pi~\delta(\omega).$$The sum of these then proves our original statement: $$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty dt~e^{i\omega t} = 2\pi~\delta(\omega).
$$

## Where were your intuitions failing you?

You perhaps thought that since $\delta(\omega)$ was even in $\omega$, it meant that $e^{i\omega t}$ was even in $t$. That is somewhat dubious reasoning in general: usually the (indefinite) integral of an even function is an odd function. However that reasoning is not 100% bad, it is just targeted at the wrong domain: it needs to be directed at a function of $t$. The real part of $e^{i\omega t}$ is indeed even and hence we can expect that the real part of the integral $0\to\infty$ is $\pi~\delta(\omega)$ just as we eventually derived. But the imaginary part is odd in $t$ and hence, we would think, it's doomed to cancel on the domain $-\infty \to \infty.$ Accordingly we could have expected that the integral $0 \to \infty$ contains some imaginary term which is the precise negative of the integral $-\infty \to 0$ such that they both cancel in the end.

Comment: +1, this answer clearly took some time to compose and format.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri Most answers by Chris tend to have a nice and clean formatting, which add value to his clear explanations. Not sure why I'm telling you this. I guess this time is as good as any other to acknowledge and appreciate his great contributions to this site. Cheers!

Comment: Well thanks for saying so! In retrospect I suppose that you're right, it's probably a dupe of something on maths.se.

Answer (score 1):

> why the half of the integral is not half of delta function?

Because the function is not even.

To illustrate why, consider:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dt e^{i\omega t}
=
\int_{-\infty}^{0} dt e^{i\omega t}+\int_{0}^{\infty} dt e^{i\omega t}
$$
$$
=
\int_0^{\infty} dse^{-i\omega s} + \int_{0}^{\infty} dt e^{i\omega t}\;,
$$
where I made the change of variable $s=-t$ in the first integral of the lower line.

But since $s$ is just a dummy variable, I can also write:
$$
=\int_0^{\infty} dte^{-i\omega t} + \int_{0}^{\infty} dt e^{i\omega t}
$$
$$
\neq 2\int_{0}^{\infty} dt e^{i\omega t}
$$

Comment: Thanks, my point is not to discuss the odd and even, my question is how to derive the second integral in the original question.

Comment: what do you mean "how to derive the second integral?" Starting from what? Ending with what? You seem to have edited your question to make it even more vague and hard to understand. Could you edit to provide some context?

Comment: My bad for the confusion. I mean $\int_{0}^{\infty}\!dt ~e^{i\omega t}$, I also re-edit the question.

Comment: I advise you to edit. What you wrote is right, but this explains why the second integral is not a delta whose argument  $\omega $ is defined on the whole real axis. The integral, infact, is a delta defined on the positive frequencies, as already mentioned in a comment above. Explain that in definition of the delta function in its integrale form you have to take into account of the definition domain of the argument.